# Checking an Excel document into SharePoint programmatically hangs

Tags: excel, powershell, sharepoint

I've been working on a PowerShell script, with the intent of refreshing a excel document's SQL data daily via task scheduler. The excel document is hosted on SharePoint. I've (after much, much trial and error) gotten it to work up until the checkin part.

- Basically, Task Scheduler fires the PowerShell script daily.
- The script creates an excel COM object.
- It verifies it can checkout the document, then does so if able.
- It then performs the refresh.
- Finally, it attempts to checkin the document. At this point, it just 
  hands and nothing happens. I should note this ONLY happens when the 
  script is run via task scheduler, and 'whether user is logged in or 
  not' is selected. If run from the PowerShell cmd line or the
  option  'user must be    logged in' is checked, everything performs
  fine.

Couple important notes-
The account is a service account user, although we granted it local login during testing. It has GOT to be unattended in practice though.
I followed the instructions for folders on this page-
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aede572b-4c1f-4729-bc9d-899fed5fad02/run-powershell-script-as-scheduled-task-that-uses-excel-com-object?forum=winserverpowershell
It is worth noting I also had to set permissions on the folders mentioned a few posts past the initial comment. I STRONGLY suspect my current issue is similar/related- but it must not be these folders because I have pretty open permissions here.

I had to remove 'enhanced IE security' as this is a server box and PowerShell  couldn't initially 'see' the SharePoint site.

I've checked the event log- the office log is apparently operational, but there is no popup at the time of checkin apparently.

I've set and verified COM permission settings, although it is possible I missed something here. Excel wasn't listed in the APP list but adding the user to the call privileges moved me forward on the task.

I'm pretty sure this doesn't happen if I run it as a dev administrator.

CYA-
I'm aware MS doesn't endorse the above, but I'm also aware people get it to work.
Powerpivot for SharePoint is not really an option at this time.
This is like my third question ever (I normally bang my head against the wall until I get it, but I'm getting a bit bloody here for 'just' a PowerShell  script. Please bear with me if I'm over/under wordy :)

Truncated script below- (removed try/catch and debug messages. If you want the cleaned full let me know, I'd love to save someone the trouble I had.)

```
$i = "http://supersecretintranetsite/excelwithsqldatacon.xlsx"


# Creating the excel COM Object 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application; 

Start-Sleep -s 5
# Setting up Excel to run without UI and without alerts
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false 
$Excel.ScreenUpdating = $false 
$Excel.Visible = $false 
$Excel.UserControl = $false 
$Excel.Interactive = $false


If ($Excel.workbooks.CanCheckOut($i))
{

    # Opening the workbook, can be local path or SharePoint URL
    $Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.Open($i);      

    # Perform the check out
    $Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.CheckOut($i)   
    $Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.Open($i);

    Start-Sleep -s 15

    # Calling the refresh
    $Workbook.RefreshAll();

    # Forces a hold until all Refreshing is done
    $Excel.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()

    # Saving and closing the workbook
    # $Workbook.Save() #- this hangs too
    Start-Sleep -s 15
    # THIS HANGS
    $Workbook.CheckInWithVersion();

    Start-Sleep -sec 5

    #Release Workbook
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook)
}
```

$Excel.quit();

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be more folder permissions. 
I added full control permissions for that user to the Appdata folder in the \windows*\config\systemprofile folders and it worked. 
I'd assigned read/write but I guess that wasn't enough.